# Using Python2.7 from command line (Linux)

Tags: python

My problem is when I try and run a python script from the command line as follows;

```
python_projects # python variable.py
```

It uses Python version 3, I wish to change this to 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line?

For example:

```
#!/path/to/2.7/python
```

Nothing is stopping you from invoking the 2.7 interpreter either:

```
./path/to/2.7/python python_projects
```

You could make a bash alias:

```
alias py27=/path/to/2.7/python
```

et voilá

```
py27 python_projects
```

Readers digest: lots of solutions.

Comment: The alias is the way to go IMHO, but you can also just make sure that the location of the python2.7 executable is located before the python3.x executable in the path. That would also work.

Comment: maybe put the alias in .bash_profile so you won't have to redo it everytime.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.something installed in default ways, the following should be true:

- `python3` always runs your best 3.x version
- EITHER:

  - `python` runs your best 2.x version, OR
  - `python` runs the same thing as `python3`, but `python2` runs your best 2.x version

So, you can always use `python2` if it exists, `python` if not.

In addition:

- `python2.7` always runs your best 2.7.x version.

So, you can just use that.

If `python2.7`, `python2`, and even `python` aren't on your PATH, or you've done some kind of weird installation that breaks the expected rules (or your distro does it for you), you can always specify Python by full path. Instead of, say, `/usr/bin/env python` or `/usr/local/bin/python` or whatever you're using, use `/opt/local/python2.7/bin/python`, or wherever you've got it installed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on a linux box, you can add something like this to your .zshrc / .bashrc file to swtich between different python versions.

```
py25() {
    rm -rf ~/.ipython
    alias ipython="/usr/local/bin/ipython-2.5"
    alias pip="/usr/local/bin/pip-2.5"
    alias python="/usr/local/bin/python-2.5"
 }

py27() {
    rm -rf ~/.ipython
    alias ipython="/usr/local/bin/ipython-2.7"
    alias pip="/usr/local/bin/pip-2.7"
    alias python="/usr/local/bin/python-2.7"
 }
py33() {
    rm -rf ~/.ipython
    alias ipython="/usr/local/bin/ipython-3.3"
    alias pip="/usr/local/bin/pip-3.3"
    alias python="/usr/local/bin/python-3.3"
 }
```

then you can just call them on the cmd line as `py25` or `py27` or `py33`. This also takes care of pip and iPython at the same time.